# Powershell GUI Label change

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, user-interface, data-binding

I am building a GUI in powershell using XAML. I will be updating the gui label/text with text of what is happening in the program.

```
for($i in $array){
  if $i -eq "item"{
   add item to matcharray
  }
}
```

Example taking this piece of code searching for matches in an array. The GUI would have its label say "searching array for matches". Then when it goes to another part of the code such as doing some math functions. The GUI would say "Doing math functions" So far I can have the GUI update with a button click but I want it to update once that piece of code is being executed. At the very least have it update on a timer. I am looking for a way to change the label text automatically. Just a small piece of code of changing a label automatically would help.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple with a bit of code here. https://foxdeploy.com/functions/ise-snippets/xaml-to-gui/

You use the function to bind the WFP object to a Powershell one, and update it accordingly.

```
$inputXML = @"
XAML
"@       

$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N'  -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
try {
    $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
} catch { 
    Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Double-check syntax and ensure .net is installed."
}

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

Function Get-FormVariables
{
    if ($global:ReadmeDisplay -ne $true) {
        Write-host "If you need to reference this display again, run Get-FormVariables" -ForegroundColor Yellow; $global:ReadmeDisplay=$true
    }
    write-host "Found the following interactable elements from our form" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    get-variable WPF*
}

Get-FormVariables

#Updates the XAML thing named "label1"
$WPFlabel1.Text = "This is the starting value!"

$WPFbutton1.Add_Click({
$WPFlabel1.Text = "This is the updated value!"
})
$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

You would just have your code inside Add_Click, and place the updated text wherever you wanted it to occur. On a timer, etc.

Comment: Good post. Pretty sure that's the exact script where I learned to use XAML in powershell :)

Comment: Thanks @CoryEtmund, I just learned it myself for a recent project so it was fresh on my mind. I definitely couldn't have done it without the resources on that site though.

Comment: That site was definitely useful. I was trying to create my first XAML form in a WPF project in visual studio and I didn't have much experience with C#. Found out I could do it with PS and was very happy from that moment on!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$Label.Text = "Whatever you want your label to say here"
```

You can add that to wherever you would like it to run in your code, multiple times if needed.

Comment: for XAML it might be `$Label.Content` too

Comment: Ya but the issue comes with updating the GUI. I can set the Text. Then after if I put another line changing the text. The GUI only shows the first set and is never updated to the second.

Comment: Do this after you update the text: `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` This will force the form to update, which should change the text.

Comment: What I have is 
   
   $window.Content = "first"
Start-Sleep -s 5
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
   $window.Content = "second"
$Window.ShowDialog()

This is only showing the second

Comment: Tried something like form.refresh() ?

Comment: `$Window.ShowDialog()` is what shows the form. If you set something before showing the form, then that is what you're going to see. In this case you will only see "second" because that is the most recent thing it was set to before you activated the form. `ShowDialog()` will stop your script and wait for interaction, `Show()` will show your form but then continue running your script. So either you change it to `$Window.Show()` and then update your text, or make a button click start the process to change the text.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can figure it out from here.

Comment: Thanks cet51. That worked great. `$btnOK.Content = "Processing..." ; [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
` worked for me. This code can be on one line which cleans things up a bit.